# String manipulation to find variables in string

Tags: javascript, string

I am working with JS and have a problem where I have two strings such as:

```
var test = "This is a {feature1} and {feature2} boy.";
var data = "This is a very good and smart boy.";
```

Considering whatever word is wrapped in `{}` is a variable, substituting the appropriate value of the variables will convert `test` to `data`.

The problem statement is we need to find the values of every word in case if the problem has a solution, otherwise, return false from the method.

So, in the above example, we have a return value as

```
{
    feature1: 'very good',
    feature2: 'smart'
}
```

So far, I have tried the below code which seems to be working though, but it seems a bit complex for this operation.

```js
function matchAndGetVar(test, data) {
    function multiSplit(data, splitters) {
        function helper(dataArray, splitter) {
            return dataArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                acc.push(...curr.split(splitter));
                return acc;
            }, []);
        }
    
        return splitters.reduce((acc, curr) => helper(acc, curr), [data]).map((f, index) => {
            if (index % 2 === 0) return f;
            return '{' + f + '}';
        });
    }

    var splittedTestData = multiSplit(test, ['{', '}']);
    
    return splittedTestData.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
        if (curr.startsWith("{") && curr.endsWith("}")) {}
        else if (index === 0) {
            if (data.startsWith(curr)) {
                data = data.substr(curr.length);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (splittedTestData[index] === "") {
            if (acc)
                acc[splittedTestData[index - 1].substr(1, splittedTestData[index - 1].length - 2)] = data;
            data = "";
        } else {
            const index1 = data.indexOf(splittedTestData[index]);
            if (index1 === -1) return false;
            if (acc)
                acc[splittedTestData[index - 1].substr(1, splittedTestData[index - 1].length - 2)] = data.substr(0, index1);
            data = data.substr(index1 + splittedTestData[index].length);
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

var test = "This is a {feature1} and {feature2} boy.";
var data = "This is a very good and smart boy.";

console.log(matchAndGetVar(test, data));
```

Can anyone suggest something simpler approach or any modification to the implementation?

Comment: functions inside functions inside functions inside functions ...

Comment: also `helper` means nothing. Every function is a helper. Name your functions with verbs that represent what they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the regex, there is an example

```js
var test = "This is a {feature1} and {feature2} boy.";
var data = "This is a very good and smart boy.";

let resp = findFeatures(test);
console.log(resp)
function findFeatures(data) {

    let features = {};

    /* EXTRACTING FEATURE KEYS */
    data.match(/\{(.+?)\}/g).forEach(result => {
        features[result.slice(1, -1)] = ""
    })

    let matches = matchWithData(test);
    if (Object.keys(features).length > 0 && matches.length == Object.keys(features).length) { // if pattern results matches with data
        Object.keys(features).forEach((feature, index) => {
            features[feature] = matches[index]
        })
    }
    return features;
}

function matchWithData(test) {

    let regex = test.replace(/\{.+?\}/g, "(.*)");

    if (new RegExp(regex).test(data)) // data matches with test
        return data.match(new RegExp(regex)).slice(1); // get features
    return [];
}
```